PermissionError: [Errno 13] SFTPサーバからダウンロードしたファイルをローカル上に書き込む事が出来ない
現在、同一ネットワーク上のSFTPサーバからアップデートファイルをダウンロードするプログラムを作成していたのですが、SFTPサーバからダウンロードした時どこに置いても必ず PermissionError [Error 13] となってしまい困っております。
以下がメインプログラムです。
クラスは以下のページを参考にしました。
PythonでSFTPに接続する方法
import pysftp
import os
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import sys
import ctypes

class Sftp:
    def __init__(self, hostname, username, password, port=22):
        """Constructor Method"""
        # Set connection object to None (initial value)
        self.connection = None
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.port = port

    def connect(self):
        """Connects to the sftp server and returns the sftp connection object"""

        try:
            # Get the sftp connection object
            self.connection = pysftp.Connection(
                host=self.hostname,
                username=self.username,
                password=self.password,
                port=self.port,
            )
        except Exception as err:
            raise Exception(err)
        finally:
            print(f"Connected to {self.hostname} as {self.username}.")

    def disconnect(self):
        """Closes the sftp connection"""
        self.connection.close()
        print(f"Disconnected from host {self.hostname}")

    def listdir(self, remote_path):
        """lists all the files and directories in the specified path and returns them"""
        for obj in self.connection.listdir(remote_path):
            yield obj

    def listdir_attr(self, remote_path):
        """lists all the files and directories (with their attributes) in the specified path and returns them"""
        for attr in self.connection.listdir_attr(remote_path):
            yield attr

    def download(self, remote_path, target_local_path):
        """
        Downloads the file from remote sftp server to local.
        Also, by default extracts the file to the specified target_local_path
        """

        try:
            print(
                f"downloading from {self.hostname} as {self.username} [(remote path : {remote_path});(local path: {target_local_path})]"
            )

            # Create the target directory if it does not exist
            path, _ = os.path.split(target_local_path)
            if not os.path.isdir(path):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(path)
                except Exception as err:
                    raise Exception(err)

            # Download from remote sftp server to local
            self.connection.get(remote_path, target_local_path)
            print("download completed")

        except Exception as err:
            raise Exception(err)

    def upload(self, source_local_path, remote_path):
        """
        Uploads the source files from local to the sftp server.
        """

        try:
            print(
                f"uploading to {self.hostname} as {self.username} [(remote path: {remote_path});(source local path: {source_local_path})]"
            )

            # Download file from SFTP
            self.connection.put(source_local_path, remote_path)
            print("upload completed")

        except Exception as err:
            raise Exception(err)

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    if not is_admin():
        # ユーザーが管理者権限を持っていない場合、新しいプロセスを管理者権限で起動
        print("権限要求")
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)

    sftp = Sftp(
        hostname="***.***.***.***",
        username="****-user",
        password="**************",
    )


    tmpath = r"C:\Users\****\Downloads\test"

    assert os.path.isdir(mmpath)

    print(tmpath)

    # Connect to SFTP
    sftp.connect()

    # Lists files with attributes of SFTP
    path = "/contents"
    #print(f"List of files with attributes at location {path}:")
    for file in sftp.listdir_attr(path):
        print(file.filename, file.st_mode, file.st_size, file.st_atime, file.st_mtime)
        sftp.download("./"+file.filename, tmpath)

    sftp.disconnect()

また、エラー個所です。
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\***\\Downloads\\test'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Error13は権限の問題と書かれていたのですが、testディレクトリには書き込み権限を振っています。
また、メインプログラムを管理者権限でも実行しています。
試しに、以下の様にファイルを作成するプログラムはエラーせずに実行できました。
path = r'C:\Users\***\Downloads\test\ww.txt'
f = open(path, 'w')
f.write('')  
f.close()


「ユーザーが管理者権限を持っていない場合、新しいプロセスを管理者権限で起動」する理由は何でしょうか？ ここを削除した場合は成功しますか？

connection.get()の第二引数には、ファイル名を含むパスを渡す必要があるように見受けます。
質問に記載のサイトより引用:

この関数は、次のように呼び出します：
connection.get("./remote.txt", "./download.txt")


ソースコードの以下の記載を
sftp.download("./"+file.filename, tmpath)

ファイル名を含むように変更してはどうでしょうか。
sftp.download("./"+file.filename, tmpath + "¥¥" + file.filename)

